# How to show and hide menu tabs in module

Tags: 7, routes

I have created tabs in module for different functions. As per code shown below, all the tabs are shown simultaneouly when I login to the module. But, I want to show specific modules depending on the play formats, how can I do that? I tried hook for menu_alter and created custom module but all hides specific menu directly and not condition wise.

## Play URLs

```
$items['abc/play'] = array(
    'title' => t('Welcome Player'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('score_entry_table'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'scoreentry.inc',
);

$items['abc/play/cricket_score'] = array(
    'title'         => t('Cricket Scoreboard'),
    'page callback' => 'cricket_score_table',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,  
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'cricketscore.inc',
    'weight' => 2   
);  
$items['abc/play/soccer_score'] = array(
    'title'         => t('Soccer Scoreboard'),
    'page callback' => 'soccer_score_table',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,  
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'soccerscore.inc',
    'weight' => 1   
);
```

Now it shows both tabs after login, I want to show only one tab as per format. I go to scoreentry page, where I get the format code and I want to hide the tab based on that format.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) Module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid showing both tabs simultaneously then you will need to manage path hierarchy. In a path hierarchy if sibling items are typo of MENU_LOCAL_TASK then they always appear in tabs simultaneously.

This is an example to break you path hierarchy in more deeper way.

```
$items['abc/play'] = array(
    'title' => t('Welcome Player'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('score_entry_table'),
    'file' => 'scoreentry.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['abc/play/cricket'] = array(
    'title' => t('Welcome Player'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('score_entry_table'),
    'file' => 'scoreentry.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['abc/play/soccer'] = array(
    'title' => t('Welcome Player'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('score_entry_table'),
    'file' => 'scoreentry.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['abc/play/cricket/score'] = array(
    'title'         => t('Cricket Scoreboard'),
    'page callback' => 'cricket_score_table',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'cricketscore.inc',
);  

$items['abc/play/soccer/score'] = array(
    'title'         => t('Soccer Scoreboard'),
    'page callback' => 'soccer_score_table',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'soccerscore.inc',

);
```